# Retrieve Firestore Data into Recylerview not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I basically want to display the data from firestore when the user selects an item from the second spinner and display it in a CardView inside RedcyclerView.
The code doesnt throw any errors but doesn't display the data either i.e nothing happens when an item is selected from the second spinner.
My Firestore Database schema is something like:
Tests > 7th (standard/grade) > Physics (subject) > QuestionNum > 1 > Document Auto-ID > qName,op1,op2,op3,op4,cop (fields).

This is QuestionListFragment.java where I want to display data

```
public class QuestionListFragment extends Fragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
Spinner spin1,spin2;
String sub,std,TAG="QuestionListFragment";
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private CollectionReference ref;
private QuestionItemAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


public QuestionListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment QuestionListFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static QuestionListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    QuestionListFragment fragment = new QuestionListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_list, container, false);

    db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    spin1=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.list_standard_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.standard));
    arrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);



    spin2= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.list_subject_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subjects));
    arrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
   spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //sub=spin2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            setUpRecylerView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    return view;
}
public void setUpRecylerView(){
    for (int i=1;i<=50;i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "setUpRecylerView: In setuprecylerview");
        std=spin1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        sub=spin2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        CollectionReference cref;

        ref=db.collection("Tests").document(std).collection(sub).document("QuestionNum").collection(String.valueOf(i));
      
        Query query = ref.orderBy("qName",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<QuestionItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<QuestionItem>()
                .setQuery(query,QuestionItem.class)
                .build();

        adapter=new QuestionItemAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }
}
}
```

This is QuestionItem.java

```
public class QuestionItem {
private String qName;
private String op1;
private String op2;
private String op3;
private String op4;
private String cop;

public QuestionItem(){
    // Empty Constructor
}

public QuestionItem(String qName, String op1, String op2, String op3, String op4, String cop){
    this.qName=qName;
    this.op1=op1;
    this.op2=op2;
    this.op3=op3;
    this.op4=op4;
    this.cop=cop;
}

public String getqName() {
    return qName;
}

public String getOp1() {
    return op1;
}

public String getOp2() {
    return op2;
}

public String getOp3() {
    return op3;
}

public String getOp4() {
    return op4;
}

public String getCop() {
    return cop;
}
}
```

This is the adapater class QuestionItemAdapter.java

```
public class QuestionItemAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<QuestionItem, 
QuestionItemAdapter.NoteHolder> {

/**
 * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
 * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public QuestionItemAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<QuestionItem> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionItemAdapter.NoteHolder holder, int position, 
@NonNull QuestionItem model) {
    holder.qname_textview.setText(model.getqName());
    holder.op1_textview.setText(model.getOp1());
    holder.op2_textview.setText(model.getOp2());
    holder.op3_textview.setText(model.getOp3());
    holder.op4_textview.setText(model.getOp4());
    holder.cop_textview.setText(model.getCop());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public QuestionItemAdapter.NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_item,parent,false);
    return new NoteHolder(v);
}

class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView qname_textview,op1_textview,op2_textview,op3_textview,op4_textview,cop_textview;

    public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        qname_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.qName_display);
        op1_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.op1_display);
        op2_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.op2_display);
        op3_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.op3_display);
        op4_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.op4_display);
        cop_textview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.correct_op_display);
    }
}
}
```

And I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAGI6jGS4vs&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuAXdWxOzsN5rgG2M4uJ8bH1) for reference.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **350** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Removed those layout XML files. Thanks for the suggestion.